# action is triggering a series of remote methods and returning rejected

Tags: reactjs, redux, loopbackjs

I have an action that is getting dispatched that is triggering multiple remote methods and returning`'TALK_SUBMIT_REJECTED'` The strange thing however, is that all of the data that I am getting is still returned and updating the store as expected.
I am however getting these two errors in the process:
`xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/api/talks/talkSubmit 500 
    (Internal Server Error)`
    `createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with 
    status code 500
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at e.exports (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.m.(:3000/anonymous function) 
    (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:6:2169)`

I have thrown in two dozen console.logs recording all of the data I am sending and receiving and everything returning as expected.

I apologize in advance for the long post but I have been struggling with this bug for a while.
to give a brief summery of what my code is doing:
I have a form that upon submission, triggers an action that starts a chain of remote methods.
This is the first method:

```
    function talkSubmit(speakerInfo, talkInfo, date) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { Talk, Speaker, Event } = app.models;
      return Speaker.create(speakerInfo)
         .then(response => {
                let speakerId = response.id
                return getMeetups()
                    .then(meetups => {
                        const index = meetups.findIndex((item) => 
                        item.date == date);
                        let name = meetups[index].name;
                        let details = meetups[index].description;
                        let meetupId = meetups[index].meetupId;
                        if (index === -1)
                            return reject(new Error('NO meetup with that 
                            date found!'));
                        return Event.findOrCreate({ date, name, details, 
                        meetupId })
                            .then(event => {
                                let eventId = event[0].id
                                return Talk.create({ ...talkInfo, 
                                speakerId, eventId })
                                    .then(talk => resolve(talk))
                                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
                            })
                            .catch(err => reject(err))
                    })
                    .catch(err => reject(err))
            })
            .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
    }

    module.exports = { talkSubmit };

//this is the get meetups function that is called by talkSubmit
    function getMeetups() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 3);
        const date ='${ currentDate.getFullYear() } -${ 
    currentDate.getMonth() } -${
    currentDate.
        getDay()
    } ';
        axios.get(`https://api.meetup.com/sandiegojs/events? 
        no_later_than = ${ date } `)
        return resolve(response.data.map(event => ({
            meetupId: event.id,
            name: event.name,
            date: event.local_date,
            time: event.local_time,
            link: event.link,
            description: event.description,
        })))
        .catch(err => reject(new Error('getMeetups failed to get SDJS 
    meetups')))
    })
    }
    module.exports = { getMeetups };

//This is the after remote method that is triggered when talkSubmit is
//completed.
    Talk.afterRemote('talkSubmit', function (ctx, modelInstance, next) {
        const speakerId = ctx.result.speakerId;
        const eventId = ctx.result.eventId;
        const approved = false;
        const pending = true;
        formatTalkForEmail(speakerId, eventId)
            .then((response) => {
            const speakerName = response.speakerName;
            const speakerEmail = response.speakerEmail;
            const meetupTitle = response.meetupTitle;
            const meetupDate = response.meetupDate;
            sendEmailToSpeaker(process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL, approved, 
            pending, speakerEmail, speakerName, meetupTitle, meetupDate)
            .then(() => next())
                .catch(err => next(err));
        })
        .catch(err => next(err));
        });

//this is the formatTalkForEmail method called in the remote method
function formatTalkForEmail(speakerId, eventId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (speakerId == undefined) {
           return reject(new Error('speakerId is undefined'));
        }

        if (eventId == undefined) {
            return reject(new Error('eventId is undefined'));
        }
        const { Speaker, Event } = app.models;
        Speaker.findById(speakerId)
            .then(speaker => {
                const speakerName = speaker.speakerName;
                const speakerEmail = speaker.speakerEmail
               return Event.findById(eventId)
                    .then(selectedEvent => {
                        const meetupTitle = selectedEvent.name;
                        const meetupDate = selectedEvent.date;
                        resolve({
                            speakerName,
                            speakerEmail,
                            meetupTitle,
                            meetupDate
                        })
                    })
                    .catch(err => reject( err ))
            })
            .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
}
module.exports = { formatTalkForEmail };

        //and finally this is the sendEmailToSpeaker method:


    function sendEmailToSpeaker(adminEmail, approved, pending, 
    speakerEmail, speakerName, meetupTitle, meetupDate) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let emailContent;
        if (approved && !pending) {
            emailContent = `Congratulations! Your request to speak at
    ${ meetupTitle } on ${ meetupDate } has been approved.`
        }
        if (!approved && !pending) {
            emailContent = `We're sorry your request to speak at 
    ${ meetupTitle } on ${ meetupDate } has been denied.`
        }
        if (pending) {
            emailContent = `Thank you for signing up to speak
    ${ meetupTitle } on ${ meetupDate }.You will be notified as soon as 
    a
    SDJS admin reviews your request.`
            sendEmailToAdmin(adminEmail, meetupDate, meetupTitle, 
    speakerEmail, speakerName)
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
        const email = {
            to: speakerEmail,
            from: adminEmail,
            subject: 'SDJS Meetup Speaker Request',
            templateId: process.env.ADMIN_SPEAKER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
            dynamic_template_data: {
                emailContent: emailContent,
                sdjsBtn: false,
                title: 'SDJS Meetup Speaker Request'
            }
        }
        sgMail.send(email)
            .then(() => resolve({ email }))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            });
    })
    }
```

in conclusion I have no clue what part of talkSubmit is throwing those two errors and yet both emails are getting automatically sent and the store is updating with all the proper data despite the initial action creator returning rejected. I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think the main problem is here:

```
axios.get(`https://api.meetup.com/sandiegojs/events?no_later_than = ${ date } `)
        return resolve(response.data.map(event => ({
            meetupId: event.id,
            name: event.name,
            date: event.local_date,
            time: event.local_time,
            link: event.link,
            description: event.description,
        })))
```

it should look like that (I recommend to extract mapping method):

```
axios.get(`https://api.meetup.com/sandiegojs/events?no_later_than = ${ date} `)
        .then( response => resolve(response.data.map(event => ({
            meetupId: event.id,
            name: event.name,
            date: event.local_date,
            time: event.local_time,
            link: event.link,
            description: event.description,
        }))))
        .catch(err => reject(new Error('getMeetups failed to get SDJS meetups')))
```

and a few words about Promises. You can chain them like that:

```
method()
.then(method2())
.then(method3())
.then(method4())
...
.catch(err =>...
```

also I don't understand why you wrap content of method in `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` I think is not needed in your case
so you can change `talkSubmit` method to something like that (this is just a draft, I recommend to extract methods from `then` blocks)

```
function talkSubmit(speakerInfo, talkInfo, date) {
    const { Talk, Speaker, Event } = app.models;
    return getMeetups()
        .then(meetups => {
            const index = meetups.findIndex((item) => item.date == date);
            let name = meetups[index].name;
            let details = meetups[index].description;
            let meetupId = meetups[index].meetupId;
            if (index === -1)
                return reject(new Error('NO meetup with that date found!'));
            return Promise.all([
                Event.findOrCreate({
                    date, name, details,
                    meetupId
                }),
                Speaker.create(speakerInfo)])
        })
        .then(([event, speaker]) => {
            let eventId = event[0].id
            let speakerId = speaker.id
            return Talk.create({
                ...talkInfo,
                speakerId, eventId
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: you my friend are a genius! I implemented your changes and I am finally getting some successful submissions. I ran the functions ten times without restarting the project. All ten new speakers added were successfully added to the database. However only 8 of them actually came back `TALK_SUBMIT_FULFILLED` in my reducer. The other two errored out with these errors :

Comment: ```xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/api/talks/talkSubmit 500 
    (Internal Server Error)  createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with 
    status code 500
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at e.exports (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.m.(:3000/anonymous function) 
    (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:6:2169)```
no clue why it is failing sometimes and not others when the code didnt change between submissions. Ill keep running tests to see whats going wrong but at least this is progress

Comment: Hmm strange I'm waiting for more test results

Comment: Any news or success?